# Vue: Check/uncheck checkbox when Grandparent or parent is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

So I am trying to check/uncheck a checkbox when grandparent or parent is checked/unchecked:

```
new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    grand_parent: false,
    parent: false
  }
})
```

However it's not working as can be seen here:

http://jsbin.com/yabewemimo/edit?html,js,output

What I am trying to acheive is:

- When grand-parent is checked/unchecked, it should affect direct children eg both parent and child
- When parent is checked/unchecked, it should affect child only

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to watch it:

```
  watch: {
    grand_parent: function (val) {
      if (val) this.parent = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it was also my first instinct but wanted to see if it was possible without computed or watch. I think expression should be `this.chk_admin_all = val` to hanlde unchecked status as well, thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working as per your expectations as you have a `v-model` on your parent, so your `:checked` property binding is not having an effect.

```
new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    grand_parent: false,
    parent_proxy: false // Because it will cause a stack overflow if
  },                    // I reference this.parent in its own computed
  computed: {
    parent: {
      get () {
        return (this.grand_parent)
          ? true 
          : this.parent_proxy
      },
      set (val) {
        this.parent_proxy = val
      }
    }
  }
})
```

the working [bin](http://jsbin.com/zucinawave/1/edit?html,js,output)